# Changing the layout of an AlertController

Tags: ios, swift, dialog

I have used the following code to try and change the layout of a UIAlertController using a nib however the dialog just shows up and looks the same each time regardless of the nib specified, it looks like a translucent grey box, at the bottom of my screen.

```
class AlertDialogViewController: UIViewController {

var message: String = ""

override init() {
    super.init(nibName: "SignUpViewController", bundle: nil)
    //Below two lines are important for custom transitions.
    transitioningDelegate = self
    modalPresentationStyle = .Custom
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

//Other code for your dialog controller
// .
// .
// .
}

extension AlertDialogViewController : UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

func transitionDuration(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) -> NSTimeInterval {
    return 0.5 //Add your own duration here
}

func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
//Add presentation and dismiss animation transition here.
}
}

extension AlertDialogViewController : UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {

func animationControllerForPresentedController(presented: UIViewController, presentingController presenting: UIViewController, sourceController source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    return self
}

func animationControllerForDismissedController(dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    return self
}

}

extension UIViewController {

func showAleartWithMessage(message: String) {
    var ad = AlertDialogViewController()
    ad.message = message
    presentViewController(ad, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

Comment: What do you want it to look like?

Answer (score 1):

You can't

> The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not
>   support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and
>   must not be modified.

Edit: Relevant code to what I said in comment is added

Imagine you want a dialog box with a UILable and two UIButtons instance

```
class CustomView : UIView {
   var commentLabel: UILable!
   var okayButton: UIButton!
   var cancelButton: UIButton!

   init(frame: CGRect) {
     super.init(frame: frame) 

     commentLabel = UILabel()
     okayButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(.Custom)
     cancelButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(.Custom)

     // TODO: Configuration such target, action, titleLable, etc. left to the user 

     [commentLabel, okayButton, cancelButton].map { self.addSubview($0) }
   }

   @IBAction func okayButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
      // TODO: Complete implementation
    }

   @IBAction func okayButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
      // TODO: Complete implementation
   }

}


class CustomAlertDialogViewCongroller : UIViewController {
  override func loadView() {
    self.view = CustomView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 100))
  }
}

// In the view controller that you want to present that alert dialog. Let's call it viewController

let customAlertDialogViewController = CustomAlertDialogViewCongroller()
customAlertDialogViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .UIModalPresentationFormSheet
customAlertDialogViewController.modalTransitionStyle = .CoverVertical

viewController.presentViewController(customAlertDialogViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: How do I change the look of a dialog box?:)

Comment: Well, you may create a view controller with your preferred view created in -loadView method of newly created view controller and present the view controller modally using

Comment: In my Xcode quite a lot of errors show up is there something I'm missing?:) @user4130613

Comment: @user3280937 paste errors on hastebin.com or somewhere else to let me see them

Comment: @user3280937 I haven't had access internet till now so it got a bit long to answer your question. Those problems are identified because you didn't create CustomView.swift file

Comment: what goes into the custom view.swift?

Comment: @user3280937 The CustomView class that I wrote above. See code snippets

Comment: It is now asking me to add an override statement onto the init(frame:CGRect) but doing this creates another error